# Jquery Droabble Box Limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make a drag drop stage using Jquery, I am having problem that I want only a single item inside the droppable box. But right now, it is adding multiple items inside it. Here is my code.

```
$("#item_list_2" ).droppable({
        drop:
                function(e, ui)
                {
                    var param = $(ui.draggable).attr('src');
                    var div_id = '#'+ $(this).attr("id");

                    addlist(param,div_id);
                }
});
```

Where addlist() is a function which is creating item contents using ajax. I there any way that I can restrict my #item_list_2 to get only one droppable object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the accept option in droppable to disable it when you have an element already dropped (you have to implement that condition depending on your case):

```
$("#item_list_2" ).droppable({
        accept: function() {
            return elementsAlreadyDropped == 0;   //<-- Implement for your concrete case
        },
        drop:
                function(e, ui)
                {
                    var param = $(ui.draggable).attr('src');
                    var div_id = '#'+ $(this).attr("id");

                    addlist(param,div_id);
                }
});
```

Comment: You have to put there a condition checking if there was a previous element dropped in that droppable.   The implementation depends on your case.  If you can share the addlist funcion implementation I can try to help you with a concrete implementation.

Comment: Thanks gustavogb for your help. One thing is not understandable for 
me where it says            
return elementsAlreadyDropped == 0; 

Can you please explain a bit more about "elementsAlreadyDropped" and how I will check if the object is already dropped. Actually I have total 8 items to be dropped in more than 20 boxes.

Many Thanks

Comment: function addlist(param,div_id)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ajax/addtobox.php",
 data: 'img='+encodeURIComponent(param),
 dataType: 'json',
 beforeSend: function(x){$('#ajax-loader').css('visibility','visible');},
 success: function(msg){
  $('#ajax-loader').css('visibility','hidden');
  if(parseInt(msg.status)!=1)
  {
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $(div_id).append(msg.txt);
  }
 });
 }
}

I don't know why it is not displaying in code format in comments